# angularjs input type radio don't Checked why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have two input radio like this :[image]

The operation work's good whene i click offre i have input text i can search for offre and whene i click entrepises clients i have input text  and i can search for entreprise. but input clicked not checked why ?
this is my code html :

```
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="{[{showHideTest1}]}" ng-model="showHideTest1" ng-value="{[{showHideTest1}]}" ng-change='newValue()'>Entreprises clientes</label>



 <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="{[{showHideTest1}]}" ng-model="showHideTest2" ng-value="{[{showHideTest2}]}" ng-change='newValue2()'>Offres</label>
```

and this in my controller

```
var adminApp = angular.module('adminApp', ['ngSanitize', 'xeditable', 'ngFileUpload', 'ui.bootstrap', 'destegabry.timeline', 'slick', 'bootstrapLightbox', 'angular-loading-bar']).config(['$interpolateProvider', function ($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
    }]);
  adminApp.controller('adminCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', '$http', '$compile', function ($scope, $modal, $http, $compile) {
     $scope.showHideTest1 = true;
        $scope.showHideTest2 = false;
    $scope.newValue = function () {
        $scope.showHideTest1 = true;
        $scope.showHideTest2 = false;

       return true;

    };
    $scope.newValue2 = function () {
       $scope.showHideTest1 = false;
       $scope.showHideTest2 = true;
       return true;
    };
 }]);
```

thank you stackoverflow

Comment: you dont need value , ng-model is enough . Try remove it

Comment: What do you mean by input clicked no checked.

Comment: i delete ng-value but i have the same result